# What passages of scripture give the strongest support for Jesus being a separate person than YHWH?

Tags: nature-of-god, non-trinitarian, unitarianism, biblical-unitarian, god-the-father

Jesus' most important commandment is the following:

> Jesus answered him, *“The first of all the commandments is: ‘Hear, O Israel, YHWH our Elohim, YHWH is 1. And you shall love YHWH your Elohim with all your heart, with all your soul, with all your mind, and with all your strength.’ This is the first commandment."*

Those who reject the triune theory do so because they interpret the scriptures to show a clear distinction between the person of YHWH(the 1 God), and His only begotten, the Son of God.

The most well known words of Jesus are recorded in John 3:16.  This is only 1 simple example of Jesus making a distinction between himself and God.

John 3:16

> For **God** so loved the world that **He** gave ***His** only begotten Son*, that whoever believes in him should not perish but have everlasting life.

Throughout scripture this theme holds very consistent and can be shown with countless verses.  There are too many to list them all.

### ***What are the BEST scriptures to support the interpretation that Jesus is not the same person as God, but rather the Son of God and a completely separate person?***

Note: In the context of this question, verses that make a distinction between YHWH and Jesus would be greater support than verses that make a distinction between the Father and Jesus (even though we know the Father is YHWH according to this interpretation).

Answer (score -2):

### What verses provide the strongest support for the notion that Jesus is not YHWH?

There are so many verses to choose from.  Therefore I will limit my list to only those which were spoken by Jesus.

Many times throughout the gospels Jesus makes a clear distinction between himself and the 1 God.

Here are some examples:

John 8:54 Authorized KJV

> Jesus answered, If I honour myself, my honour is nothing: it is ***my Father*** that honoureth me; of whom ye say, that **HE** is **your God(YHWH).**

Luke 4:18 (Jesus reads from a **scroll** in the synagogue.)

> "The Spirit of **YHWH** is upon **ME**, because **HE** hath anointed **ME** to preach the gospel to the poor; **HE** hath sent **ME** to heal the brokenhearted, to preach deliverance to the captives, and recovering of sight to the blind, to set at liberty them that are bruised,"

Matthew 22

> 43 He(Jesus) said to them, “How then does David in the Spirit call Him ‘Lord,’ saying:
> 44 **‘YHWH said to my Lord**, “Sit at My right hand,
> Till I make Your enemies Your footstool” ’?

Mark 12:26-27 (Jesus speaking to the Pharisees, quoting scripture)

> 26 But concerning the dead, that they rise, have you not read in the book of Moses, in the burning bush passage, how **God(YHWH) spoke** to him, saying, *‘I am the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob’?* 27 ***HE*** is not the God of the dead, but the God of the living. You are therefore greatly mistaken.”
> Another very good example is when Satan is tempting Jesus in the desert.

Matt 4

> 8 Again, the devil took Him up on an exceedingly high mountain, and showed Him all the kingdoms of the world and their glory. 9 And he said to Him, “All these things I will give You if You will fall down and worship me.”
>
> 10 Then Jesus said to him, “Away with you, Satan! For it is written, ***‘You shall worship YHWH your God, and Him only you shall serve.’ ”***

Now we must ask ourselves: Why is Jesus quoting the Shema here?  Jesus is not telling Satan that he only worships and serves himself.  Rather Jesus is using the command to counter Satan's attempt to temp him, a man who only worships YHWH.

Next, if we take Jesus words literally about his Father being the **only True God** and that **YHWH is 1**, we can conclude that the Father is YHWH, and Jesus is the Son of YHWH.

Here are some examples of clear statements by Jesus telling us that his Father (not himself) is the the 1 God.

John 17:3 (Jesus speaking to his God and Father)

> And this is eternal life, that they may know **You, the only true God**, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.

John 20:17

> Jesus said to her, “Do not cling to Me, for I have not yet ascended to My Father; but go to My brethren and say to them, **‘I am ascending to My Father and your Father, and to My God and your God.’** ”

Jesus speaks so that he can be understood by children with ears to hear.  His words are purposeful and meaningful.  Included in his words are the pronouns he uses to reference the 1 God.

Jesus uses plural personified pronouns when referencing himself and his Father.

John 14:23
King James Version

> 23 Jesus answered and said unto him, If a man love me, he will keep my words: and my Father will love him, and **WE** will come unto him, and make **OUR** abode with him.

Comment: Your answer is premised on two assumptions which you have not proven, i.e. that "God" is "YHWH" and that "Jesus" is not God.  I might agree with one of those assumptions, but the other will take a little more effort on your part to establish, especially since "YHWH" is a name, and Jesus said he had come in his Father's name (see John 5:43).  If that name is used by _both_ Jesus and his Father, then your answer cannot be maintained upon the evidence you have provided.

Comment: @Biblasia This question is asking for the best examples of scripture which support the notion that Jesus is not YHWH.  My answer lists some of the best ones.  But not all of them.  Nothing subjective is ever proven.

Comment: @Biblasia The Shema is in the premise of the question.  Do I need to repeat it in my answer?  Would that be suffice for you to "prove" that YHWH is God?  Do I need to explain what "coming in the Father's name" means?  This is outside the scope of the question which is asking for a list of best scripture examples.

Comment: The Shema specifies that "YHWH" is "elohim," but the Hebrew "elohim" is not the same as the English "God."  The Hebrew word can mean angels, judges, or people--and an angel is a messenger or a spokesperson for the one who has sent the messenger.  Jesus is God's spokesperson, i.e. "the Word," and therefore fits the "elohim" definition.

Comment: YHWH our Elohim, YHWH is 1.  Yes elohim is use as a title for persons other than YHWH.  In the case of the Shema we know by context that Elohim is YHWH and He is singlular.  Are you suggesting that Elohim is never referring to the Father only?  Again, this answer is not a complete "proof" of anything.  It was not meant to be.  I honestly do not understand your critique.

Comment: YHWH is the name used by both Father and Son.  God is a single Being, but when one tries to differentiate between God and Jesus one must be careful, as the Bible says plainly that the Father is the only true God, and the Man Jesus is the Father's Son.  The difficulty is, if the New Testament name "Jesus" applies to both Father and Son, how do we know the precise application of "YHWH"?  You are attempting to say that "YHWH" is _not_ Jesus, as I understand your question, which is quite possibly incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147610/discussion-between-read-less-pray-more-and-biblasia).